# Unable to publish in Azure artifact using gradle publish

Tags: gradle, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am currently using gradle publish to be able to ublish the jar into Azure Artifact.
I have followed the instructions as:

```
`maven {
url 'https://azuredevops.url/organization-name/project-name/_packaging/artifact/maven/v1'
name 'name'
authentication {
    basic(BasicAuthentication)
}}`
```

Add or edit the settings.xml file in ${user.home}/.m2

```
    `<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                              https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>id</id>
      <username>username</username>
      <password>[PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN]</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>`
```

and after using gradle publish, I received:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':publishMavenJavaPublicationToartifactnameRepository'.

> Failed to publish publication 'mavenJava' to repository 'artifact name'
> Could not GET 'https://azuredevops.url/organization-name/project-name/_packaging/artifact/maven/v1/com/name/apps/utils/name/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

After clicking on the link I get following:

```
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"File name 'maven-metadata.xml'.' does not start 
     with artifactId 'artifact-name'","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Maven.WebApi.Exceptions.MavenInvalidFilenameException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Maven.WebApi","typeKey":"MavenInvalidFilenameException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
```

Can someone help here ?

Comment: Did you replace the Personal Access Token in this line `<password>[PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN]</password>` with one you generated? The token needs read and write scopes. So your settings.xml should look something like `<password>lkjfds7987dsfhkdfhf87hkjkj</password>`

Comment: Yes, I did changed that to the PAT which has full access.

Comment: you also need to have some gradle plugin to get the user/pw from settings.xml. Azure devops suggests `net.linguica.maven-settings:0.5` in it's "get the tools" seciton when you click on "connect to feed". Normally, gradle does not take any settings from maven settings.xml. but this plugin does the trick.

Comment: As checked, the plugin net.linguica.maven-settings:0.5 is already there in build.gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly for PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]

Keytool import certificate command

```
1. keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias mdecert -file Certificate.cer -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit

2. keytool -list -keystore "/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0/lib/security/cacerts"
```

Then 403 was faced, for that

The issue resolved once the proxy settings were changed as in case of `gradle publish` the traffic was coming towards the Azure Artifacts and proxy was not required there. Hence I added nonproxyhosts alongwith the URL in `gradle.properties` file which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step you could try to add the authentication directly into the Gradle file and if everything works then use the Maven settings file:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username "token name"
                password "password"
            }
            URL 'feed URL
            name 'feed name'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is important to note that the `username` is the token name of the personal access token of azure. Also to use the maven settings file, it is mentioned that another plugin is required:

[image: Get the tools in azure]

However, one could store credentials also in a  `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file, as this file is generally not committed.